# Extract a .zip.part file

Tags: zip, extract

I downloaded a Canon MF4410 Driver for Linux.
I got a `.zip.part` file, and the `unzip` command in the terminal doesn't work with it.

Is it possible to extract such a file?

Answer (score 6):

A .zip.part file is an incomplete piece of a .zip file that has been only partially downloaded. You should either try to download the file again or search for the complete zip file and download that file.

You can download the Linux driver for the Canon i-SENSYS MF4410 multifunction 3-in-1 laser printer from the Canon website at [this link](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/Laser/LaserBase_MF_series/i-SENSYS_MF4410.aspx?type=download&language=EN&os=Linux). This printer driver provides printing functions for UFRII-enabled Canon printers operating under the CUPS (Common UNIX Printing System) environment, a printing system that operates on Linux operating systems. To use this software, read the [online manual](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/Laser/LaserBase_MF_series/i-SENSYS_MF4410.aspx?type=manuals&language=EN) 
before installing the driver.

The o147jen_linuxufrII_0290.zip archive from the Canon website has the installation instructions for Debian-based operating systems such as Ubuntu in the README-ufr2-2.9xUK.txt file. The installation files for Ubuntu in the zip archive are as follows:

Installation package for the CUPS driver common module used by the Canon UFR II
Printer Driver for Linux
- cndrvcups-common_2.90-X_i386.deb (for Debian 32-bit)
- cndrvcups-common_2.90-X_amd64.deb (for Debian 64-bit)

Installation package for the Canon UFR II Printer Driver for Linux
- cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_2.90-X_i386.deb (for Debian 32-bit)
- cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_2.90-X_amd64.deb (for Debian 64-bit)

If you install "cndrvcups-common" package version 2.90, make sure you install the same version of the "cndrvcups-ufr2" package, i.e. 2.90.

The README-ufr2-2.9xUK.txt also has some other instructions for using the printer in Ubuntu. Search for the keyword *Ubuntu* in the README file.

Select the installation packages that match the architecture of your operating system, either 32-bit or 64-bit. The way to install a .deb file in Ubuntu is to double click on the .deb file and it will open for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center. Then install it in the Ubuntu Software Center the same way you would install any other package.

Comment: First of all. Thanks for your answer.
Actually, i did all the steps you mentioned above, but the manual doesn't provide the way to how to install the driver.
I re-downloaded the driver - and yes - there is no more .part. it's only .zip.
this way was usefull too
http://askubuntu.com/questions/182529/how-do-i-get-my-canon-mf4410-printer-to-work
but the point still the same. I got the driver but i can not install it or let Ubuntu recognize it because when i try to use GUI to add a printer on Ubuntu 14. it askes for a PPD.gz file, and the canon drivers are not.

Comment: I have added the installation instructions for Ubuntu which are in the.zip archive you downloaded to my answer as you asked.

Comment: I have added the installation instructions for Ubuntu which are in the.zip archive you downloaded to my answer as you asked
Do you mean you are the person who wrote the Readme file in the driver package?
Excuse me if i misunderstanding your comment. I am not that good in english, and this is my third day to use Ubuntu (Linux OS, in general)
Doesn't Ubuntu provide any books for dummies?!

Comment: I did install the 
- cndrvcups-common_2.90-X_amd64.deb (for Debian 64-bit)
and
- cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_2.90-X_amd64.deb (for Debian 64-bit) 
now i can see an icon with a printer 
Canon-MF4400-UFRII-LT
but trying to print a page from libreoffice or even a test page...no respond
I think Ubuntu doesn't support such a model
it's an MF4410

Comment: The README suggests for Ubuntu 13.10 or later from the terminal run this command: `sudo apt-get install libcups2 libxml2:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libstdc++6:i386` and then try to print a test page or a text file. Ubuntu provides free PDF books **Getting Started with Ubuntu 14.04** about how to get started using Ubuntu, but not in Arabic unfortunately. No, I didn't write the README, I just extracted it from the .zip archive and then read it.

Comment: [Ubuntuguide مترجمة إلى العربية عن طريق جوجل](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Trusty_arabic). I can't read Arabic, but if you visit that webpage and click the link it will open a book about Ubuntu (أوبونتو 14.04 LTS (الواثق الطهر)) in Arabic to read online. I can't read Arabic, but you can also download the English version of the same book in 3 parts (3 PDF files) for free.